# Declaring an async method in a typescript module

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm trying to write a type definitions file for an npm module so everything I'm doing is within a `declare module 'module-name' {}` block. One of the exported members of the module is an asynchronous method. I haven't yet found a way to add it.

Does it need to be declared an `async` function or should the signature just be a function returning a `Promise`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should just be a function returning a `Promise`.  The `async` modifier is only relevant when you are giving the function implementation.